# Local First Day of the Week

Tags: time

How can I change the First Day of the Weeks into Ubuntu Studio 15.10?

I'm not talking about if the first day of the week is Sunday, or Monday, or another. I know how to fix this (first day of the week is Sunday by definition).

I'm talking about the day when a week becomes the week number x (new week).

Even the fact that in my system the first day of the week is Sunday, when the computer time reaches that day (Sunday), it counts this as the last week, not a new week number x+1.

How can I change this behaviour?